# standard encryption decryption across different platforms

Tags: asp.net, objective-c, security, asp-classic, cryptography

hey guys i need to implement a standard encryption decryption logic across an entire project platform which has different clients implemented using different platforms as follows:

1. iphone app (objectiv c)
2. website (classic asp)
3. webservice (asp.net)
4. samsung bada app (c++)

the iphone app as well as the website need to send info to webservice using encrypted query strings

the web service then decrypts this and processes the info further

wanted to know the simplest way to achieve this. is there some free and ready to use binary available with an easy to use api to achieve this?

encryption needs to be as secure as possible

**edited**: currently we use AES on the website and webservice front

thnx in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Luckily encryption algorithms are well defined by standards (at least the good ones), so you should be able to find inter operable implementations for the required platforms. You probably want to use AES for the encryption?

Any idea how you will distribute the keys?

Comment: hey douglas - the keys remain within the organization - as all of these are internal projects within the organization... currently the webservice and website use AES... would update my question with more info... thnx

Comment: @Raj - The iphone app won't remain in the organization - it'll go on people's iphones.

Answer (score 3):

Can't this be solved by using HTTPS for the web service?

Comment: I agree, KISS (Keep It Simple Stupid) is the best way to go unless there is an unstated reason...